# Is there any reason that $\arctan(e)\approx e-\frac32$ or is it just pure number luck?

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, constants

Is there an informative interpretation to why $$\arctan(e)\approx e-\frac32$$

They differ by $1.07 \times 10^{-6}$.

Comment: Probably just a coincidence. These coincidences are easier to find than one might originally suspect. For instance, $e^\pi-\pi\approx 19.999$. There are just so darn many different seemingly simple expressions one can write that our would be a notable if some of them weren't close. Besides, what does "luck" really mean in this case?

Comment: Maybe try looking at the Taylor series for tan(x).